# Hosting git server lighter than gitlab without ssh

Tags: git, webserver

I have a lightly-resourced VPS running nginx and ssh. I can't afford to add more resources to it so that it can run gitlab (gitlab requires 4 GB of RAM). Until now I've been using it as a git server over ssh, but now at work I can't ssh through the proxy (and don't want to circumvent the proxy).

I'm wondering what git hosting solutions there are for me so that I can at least clone from my personal git repositories. A lighter (and maybe CLI-only) alternative to gitlab would be ideal.

It doesn't particularly matter whether the repos are kept private, but it's preferable that they are.

Answer (score 1):

Git comes with its own `git-http-backend`, a CGI application that provides fetch & push over HTTP(S). You'll find instructions for several most common web servers in its manual page. Authentication is also done through the web server (e.g. HTTP Basic).

An example read-only configuration for nginx + fcgiwrap might be:

```
location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param  GIT_PROJECT_ROOT  /home/grawity/pub/git;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO         $uri;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER       $remote_user;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
}
```

Note that git-http-backend provides *only* Git remote operations, i.e. clone/fetch/push. If you also need a graphical web interface for *browsing* your repositories, that has to be installed separately. Common graphical interfaces are cgit, gitweb, and Gitea/Gogs.

Comment: Ah thanks. I'd heard about that but had trouble searching for how to configure it since `git server` or searches like it always talk about ssh. Having the search term `git http backend` is very useful.